# Will a mid-range wide-angle lens open up creative possibilities for landscape, when I already have a kit zoom?

Tags: lens, nikon, landscape, wide-angle, kit-lens

I am still new and finding interest in landscape photography. I have a Nikon D90 with the 18-105mm kit lens. I have been playing with it for some time.

My question is: will any **mid-range wide angle** help me (quality/creativity) in a way that my current kit lens is not able to do? 
Will that be worthwhile?

Comment: 2 thoughts: 18mm on DX is wide angle, I assume you mean an ultra wide angle. What is it that you think you need from a wider angle lens but are unsure of? Do you feel like your shots are dull, or just not getting enough stuff in for example?

Comment: Lighting is all-important in landscape photography. Get out of bed early and you're half-way there.

Comment: @AthomSfere thank you for narrowing it down. "Do you feel like your shots are dull?" Yes and this is the prior problem for me. Being a noob I really don't know is it my photography sense/skill Or  the lens to blame.

Comment: @Saif If you post a separate question and include a photo or two of yours plus reference some for comparison that you are trying to emulate, we might be able to help point you in the proper direction for how to get photos more to your liking, whether that means getting a better lens or changing some completely different aspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My gut says to me that this is one of those questions where if you have to ask, it isn't a gear problem.

When you need a wider and lens you will start to feel it. For example this shot[image]

It was a tight space, with a Nikon D7100 and a 18-55mm lens, shot at 18mm. There are certainly technical problems with the image, but I would have loved to have been able to "pull back" further and get more of the room into the shot.

[image]

That shot is the same lens, also at 18mm on a D90. Is it a cover shot or award winner? No, but I like the colors and reflections of a dusk night at a random Burger King.

With a wider lens (not even on my radar at the time) I could have gotten a lot closer. Instead I had to walk around until things looked about like I wanted.

I think that is probably where you want to be (without seeing your actual shots). Walk around, get closer or further. Wait for the right light, zoom in and zoom out. Identify why you think your photos are dull and work on that.

Finally, it's digital. Feel free to botch some shots. Pay attention to some of the basic rules (like the rule of thirds) and then feel free to break them. You will start to "feel" the scene better for it. And finally PP.

I rarely do much post-processing. Most of it is cropping, and a quick run through DxO (A recent change for me).

This is 24mm (about the same as 18mm on DX) on a D750 that I shot wide and then cropped to make it feel wider: But it is nothing an 18mm or 24mm lens can't do!

[image]

My short answer: You probably don't need a wider lens as much as more time with the camera.

Good luck!

Comment: How do you "crop" an image to make it feel "wider" ???? Crop has always meant to remove or close in on the subject, not add stuff to the edges of an image.

Comment: @GeorgeMcGinn Yes, you are correct. I'll crop the top and or bottom to make the image wider (as in aspect ratio away from the 3:2 to something like 20:1, 16:9 or whatever "feels right"). Nothing is added.

Comment: I wanted to make sure the person, who may be a beginner, understands that, yes, when cropping, you only take away from the image, and that, depending on what you take away, you can change the aspect ratio to mimic a wide-angle. An 18-105mm lens? WOW. Why did I buy my 17mm prime? Thanks for clarifying. Voted your comment up 1